# Form submit with AJAX passing form data to PHP without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

Can anyone tell me why this bit of code isn't working?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('form').bind('submit', function () {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="time" value="00:00:00.00"><br>
      <input name="date" value="0000-00-00"><br>
      <input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I push submit nothing happens. In the receiving php file I'm using $_POST['time'] and $_POST['date'] to put the data in a mysql query but it's just not getting the data. Any suggestions? I'm assuming it's something to do with the submit button but I can't figure it out

Comment: did u try event.preventDefault() instead of return false

Comment: also don't use submit event.use CLICK event

Comment: Don't you need to use type="submit" instead of type="button"?

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document."

Comment: The only problem is input type, you don't have a submit button.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The form is submitting after the ajax request.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="time" value="00:00:00.00"><br>
      <input name="date" value="0000-00-00"><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: should use `preventDefault in the first line` of the event of `on('submit'...`

Comment: @EASI It's not a problem.$.ajax part work along So it's not a problem

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks so much. I knew something was wrong with the button but I didn't have a clue about the preventDefault

Comment: @samitha @EASI is right, if a JS fatal error happens then the `preventDefault` won't be hit and the page will reload, debug difficult, better to use prevenDefault ASAP.

Comment: @KevinBowersox can i get help regard AJAX at https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-get-two-values-in-ajax-with-same-condition   I need to pass two value. The value 1 passing good, how to pass my second value with the same condition.

Answer (score 19):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('form').bind('click', function (event) {
        // using this page stop being refreshing 
        event.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="time" value="00:00:00.00"><br>
      <input name="date" value="0000-00-00"><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["date"]) || isset($_POST["time"])) {
$time="";
$date="";
if(isset($_POST['time'])){$time=$_POST['time']}
if(isset($_POST['date'])){$date=$_POST['date']}

echo $time."<br>";
echo $date;
}
?>
```

Comment: ["Returning false from an event handler will automatically call event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault()"](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Little bug in second 'if': it should be "if(isset($_POST['date'])){$date=$_POST['date']}"

Answer (score 10):

JS Code

```
    $("#submit").click(function() { 
    //get input field values
    var name            = $('#name').val(); 
    var email           = $('#email').val();
    var message         = $('#comment').val();
    var flag = true;
    /********validate all our form fields***********/
    /* Name field validation  */
    if(name==""){ 
        $('#name').css('border-color','red'); 
        flag = false;
    }
    /* email field validation  */
    if(email==""){ 
        $('#email').css('border-color','red'); 
        flag = false;
    } 
    /* message field validation */
    if(message=="") {  
       $('#comment').css('border-color','red'); 
        flag = false;
    }
    /********Validation end here ****/
    /* If all are ok then we send ajax request to email_send.php *******/
    if(flag) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "email_send.php", 
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'username='+name+'&useremail='+email+'&message='+message,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#submit').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="image/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
                $('.wait').remove();
            },  
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data.type == 'error')
                {
                    output = '<div class="error">'+data.text+'</div>';
                }else{
                    output = '<div class="success">'+data.text+'</div>';
                    $('input[type=text]').val(''); 
                    $('#contactform textarea').val(''); 
                }

                $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();           
                }
        });
    }
});
//reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
$("#contactform input, #contactform textarea").keyup(function() { 
    $("#contactform input, #contactform textarea").css('border-color',''); 
    $("#result").slideUp();
});
```

HTML Form

```
<div  class="cover">
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="contactform">
    <p class="contact"><label for="name">Name</label></p>
    <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Yourname" type="text">

    <p class="contact"><label for="email">Email</label></p>
    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="admin@admin.com" type="text">

    <p class="contact"><label for="comment">Your Message</label></p>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" tabindex="4"></textarea> <br>
    <input name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Send Mail" type="submit" style="width:200px;">
</div>
```

PHP Code

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

    //exit script outputting json data
    $output = json_encode(
            array(
                'type' => 'error',
                'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
    ));

    die($output);
}

//check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
if (!isset($_POST["username"]) || !isset($_POST["useremail"]) || !isset($_POST["message"])) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
    die($output);
}

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$username = filter_var(trim($_POST["username"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$useremail = filter_var(trim($_POST["useremail"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$message = filter_var(trim($_POST["message"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//additional php validation
if (strlen($username) < 4) { // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short!'));
    die($output);
}
if (!filter_var($useremail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
    die($output);
}
if (strlen($message) < 5) { //check emtpy message
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Too short message!'));
    die($output);
}

$to = "info@wearecoders.net"; //Replace with recipient email address
//proceed with PHP email.
$headers = 'From: ' . $useremail . '' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $useremail . '' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$sentMail = @mail($to, $subject, $message . '  -' . $username, $headers);
//$sentMail = true;
if (!$sentMail) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please contact administrator.'));
    die($output);
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'message', 'text' => 'Hi ' . $username . ' Thank you for your email'));
    die($output);
}
```

This page has a simpler example
http://wearecoders.net/submit-form-without-page-refresh-with-php-and-ajax/

Answer (score 6):

Here is a nice plugin for jQuery that submits forms via ajax:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

its as simple as:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
           alert('form was submitted');
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

It uses the forms action for the post location.
Not that you can't achieve this with your own code but this plugin has worked very nicely for me!

Answer (score 6):

JS Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/   libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(function() {
  $(".submit").click(function() {
  var time = $("#time").val();
  var date = $("#date").val();
  var dataString = 'time='+ time + '&date=' + date;

if(time=='' || date=='')
{
  $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
  $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
     $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
     $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
    }
  });
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

HTML Form

```
   <form>
      <input id="time" value="00:00:00.00"><br>
      <input id="date" value="0000-00-00"><br>
      <input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
<span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
<span class="success" style="display:none"> Form Submitted Success</span>
</div>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$date=$_POST['date'];
$time=$_POST['time'];
mysql_query("SQL insert statement.......");
}else { }

?>
```

Taken From [Here](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/04/submit-form-jquery-and-ajax.html)

Answer (score 3):

`type="button`"

should be

```
type="submit"
```

Answer (score 1):

In event handling, pass the object of event to the function and then add statement i.e.
event.preventDefault();

This will pass data to webpage without refreshing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#userForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
//I had an issue that the forms were submitted in geometrical progression after the next submit. 
// This solved the problem.
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // show that something is loading
    $('#response').html("<b>Loading data...</b>");

    // Call ajax for pass data to other place
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'somephpfile.php',
    data: $(this).serialize() // getting filed value in serialize form
    })
    .done(function(data){ // if getting done then call.

    // show the response
    $('#response').html(data);

    })
    .fail(function() { // if fail then getting message

    // just in case posting your form failed
    alert( "Posting failed." );

    });

    // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
    return false;

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>enter code here
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="msg"></div>
            <form method="post" class="frm" id="form1" onsubmit="">
               <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="enter your first neme" required>
           <!--><span class="sp"><?php// echo $f_err;?></span><!-->
          </div>
        <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="enter your last neme" required>
              <!--><span class="sp"><?php// echo $l_err;?></span><!-->
             </div>
              <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="enter your email Address" required>
              <!--><span class="sp"><?php// echo $e_err;?></span><!-->
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="number" class="form-control" name="mno" id="mno" placeholder="enter your mobile number" required>
              <!--><span class="sp"><?php //echo $m_err;?></span><!-->
             </div>
              <div class="form-group">
               <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" id="pass" pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,8}" placeholder="enter your Password" required>
              <!--><span class="sp"><?php //echo $p_err;?></span><!-->
             </div>
              <div class="radio">
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" id="gender" checked>male<br>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" id="gender">female<br>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="other" name="gender" id="gender">other<br>
                                         <!--><span class="sp"> <?php //echo $r_err;?></span><!-->
             </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" checked>I Agree Turms&Condition<br>
                   <!--><span class="sp"> <?php //echo $c_err;?></span><!-->
                 </div>
                 <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-warning" name="submit" id="submit">
             </form>enter code here

          </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
         </div> 

    </div>
```

Comment: adding some explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(function () {
    $(".submit").click(function (event) {
      var time = $("#time").val();
      var date = $("#date").val();
      var dataString = 'time=' + time + '&date=' + date;
      console.log(dataString);
      if (time == '' || date == '')
      {
        $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
        $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
      } else
      {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "post.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function (data) {
            $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $("#data").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
  <input id="time" value=""><br>
  <input id="date" value=""><br>
  <input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit" class="submit">
</form>
<div id="data"></div>
<span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
<span class="success" style="display:none"> Form Submitted Success</span>

<?php

print_r($_POST);
if ($_POST['date']) {
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  $time = $_POST['time'];
  echo '<h1>' . $date . '---' . $time . '</h1>';
}
else {

}
?>
```