# How to submit a form using Ajax from a mobile application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I need to submit the form below (components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php. ) using Ajax.

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=user.login'); ?>" method="post">

    <fieldset>
        <?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset('credentials') as $field): ?>
            <?php if (!$field->hidden): ?>
                <div class="login-fields"><?php echo $field->label; ?>
                <?php echo $field->input; ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
                     ......
</form>
```

My Ajax request will come from external mobile App (on click, I run javaScript with Ajax to submit the form).

Is that possible? If yes, what parameters should I pass to the Ajax request (based on the example here : "[Form submit with AJAX passing form data to PHP without page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616250/form-submit-with-ajax-passing-form-data-to-php-without-page-refresh)" I need to pass url, data and success).

If that is possible, I'm also able to pass username and password (which the form fetch them from fieldset), I can provide them in plain text (no security concerns about that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use serialize: [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

In your case add an ID or name to your form or if its the only form in the page you can just:

```
$('selectorOfButtonThatTriggers').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $('form').attr('action'),
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                   alert(data);
            }
    });
});
```

All your form field will be fetch and on the server side the POST keys will be the fields input names.

To add some more data programatically you can use:

```
data: $('form').serialize() + "&more1=" + more1value
```

Comment: The website is on different server. Don't I need some URL to the file where the form locates?

Comment: I managed to submit the form. But the form itself is fetching the credentials from username and password fields website's login page (they are empty when I submit the form). I need to pass these values with the request itself such that the form read them from my request. Do I need to amend the form?