# how to get return value after form submit

Tags: javascript

I want to get the return value for hid and show div after form submit success

```
<form id='form1' action='api.php' method='post'><input ></input></form>
<div id='layer1'></div>
```

I tried:
Js

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e){ 
e.preventdefault();
$('#layer1').show();
});
```

It doesn't work. Is there anythings that I should return in the api.php?
As I am using php5.2 I cannot using something like formdata to upload image when doing form submit.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you use $('#layer').show(); or $('#layer1').show();?

Comment: Since you do `preventDefault()`, the form is never submitting. So there's no return value.

Comment: The id is `layer1` you have a typo.

Comment: What doesn't work? Error message or just nothing? I notice you are mixing layer1 and #layer. If you fix that does it work as you want?

Comment: You also have a typo in `preventDefault`. The `D` is upper-case.

Comment: If you prevent the default form submission, you need to perform an AJAX call to get the return data.

Comment: if you need some values AFTER submit you should use ajax, here is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616250/form-submit-with-ajax-passing-form-data-to-php-without-page-refresh

Comment: I typed layer1 and preventDefault.But after submit nothing return. It is not a ajax submit?

Comment: No it's not, please take a look at my answer above, there is a link, where you can see, how an ajax submit with jQuery is done

Comment: However I am using php5.2 and the form need to submit an image. Can I use ajax to submit form with image?

Comment: take a look here, this might work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image

Comment: Thanks in advance, I will try

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using origin form submit, add a listener on event 'submit'(or just as you did, invoke `.submit()`, no difference), then prevent default behavior, do it using AJAX. See [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)