# Submiting a contact form without refreshing the webpage

Tags: php, html

Here is my code which I am using in my website. I have a single page website. As I click my submit button, my whole page gets refreshed.

Please help me out with this issue. For refrence, visit http://www.creativemacky.com

```
<?php
    $to      = 'my email';
    $email   = $_POST['email'];

    $name  = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['text-massage'];

    $headers = 'From: http://www.creativemacky.com'. '<'.$email.'>' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '. $email . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
     echo "<script>window.location.href = 'http://www.creativemacky.com';</script>";
    }

?>

<form class="_form-inline row" id="contact-form" name="contact" method="post" action="contact.php">
                                    <div class="form-group custom-form-group col-sm-6">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="name" id="name"><span class="required">*</span>Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control custom-form-control wow bounceInLeft animated" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group custom-form-group col-sm-6">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="email" id="email"><span class="required">*</span>Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control custom-form-control wow bounceInRight animated" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group custom-form-group col-sm-12">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="text-massage"><span class="required">*</span>Massage</label>
                                        <textarea  class="form-control custom-form-control wow bounceInUp animated" id="text-massage" name="text-massage" rows="3" placeholder="Write something" required></textarea>
                                    </div>

                                    <button type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-default submit-button custom-white wow bounceInLeft animated" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">Say Hello</button>
                                </form>
```

Comment: I think in your code you need to check if the form is submitted by checking if $_POST['submit'] is set.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split the php from the page in order to submit without refreshing [php ajax form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616250/form-submit-with-ajax-passing-form-data-to-php-without-page-refresh) this should help you with submitting without refreshing the page.

Comment: I have my PHP script in a another page which is being called to my HTML

Answer (score 0):

Normally to post form data to a server without refreshing you need to use JavaScript. In JavaScript you catch the "submit" event and use AJAX to send the data to the server. This is easy with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

```
<script>

    $( "#contact-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        var data = {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            textMessage: $('#text-message').val()
        }
        $.post('contact.php', data);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```