# Error "Email already exists" appears on pop up form only after opening it second time

Tags: php, html, forms, registration

I have a pop up registration form, registration works well but if user inputs invalid email and submit the form it closes and when user opens it another time or refreshes the page then only the error appears means error message works but not at proper time or I don't know what is happens.

This is my PHP registration code :

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $password = md5($_POST["password"]);
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mysql");
    mysqli_select_db($link,"myuser");
    $count = 0;
    $res = mysqli_query($link,"select * from register where email='$_POST[email]'") ;
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);

if ($count>0) {
        $emailErr = "Email already exists"; 

    }



  else{
    mysqli_query($link,"insert into register values('','$_POST[username]' ,'$_POST[email]' ,'$password')");
    header("location:index.php");
  }
}

    ?>
```

This is my html pop up form code :

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<div class="modal2">

<div class="modal2_close close2"></div>

<div class="modal2_main">

        <div class="login-screen">
            <div class="app-title">
                <h1>Sign Up</h1>
            </div>


             <div><img src="images/common.png" class="circle"></div>

            <div class="login-form">
                <div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="username" name="username" required pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]+">
                <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group2">
                <input type="text" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="Email" name="email" required pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]+">
                <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
                <span><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                <input type="password" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="password" name="password" required 
                 pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]+">
                <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>

                </div>

                <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block">Register</button>

            </div>
        </div>

</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You must not have shown all relevant code - the message `Email already exists` is not anywhere in the question

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you submit your form. it will reload the page. and definitely popup will close after submit the form.

So what I will suggest you to submit form using ajax and display success/error message according to ajax response.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616250/form-submit-with-ajax-passing-form-data-to-php-without-page-refresh) link to know how you can submit form using ajax

Comment: yes it works but preventing inserting data into database

Comment: any other way plz

Comment: Mysql connection should be there in ajax file. Send me error log if you already tried this

Comment: There is no error but when I click on register  it doesn't submits form.