# How to post data (form) without page refresh PHP, jQuery, Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Please help me how to submit form (comments) without page refresh for

HTML markup:

```
<form id="commentf" method="post">
    <img width="40px" height="40px" src="uploads/<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>">
    <textarea class="textinput"id="comment" rows="1" name="comments" placeholder="Comment Here......"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" id="comq"name="compost" class="butn2">post comment</button>
</form>
```

PHP code (`pnf.php`):

```
if(isset($_POST["compost"]))
{
    $comment=$_POST['comments'];
    {
        $reslt_user= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users,`queries` where id='".$_SESSION['id']."' AND  qid= '".$qid."' ");
        $row_lat_lng= mysqli_fetch_array($reslt_user);
        $stmt = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO comments set uid='".$_SESSION['id']."',comments='".$comment."',reply='".$reply."' ,
        qid= '".$qid."' ");
    }
    if($stmt)
    {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
```

jQuery and Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#comq").click(function() {
         var comment=$("#comment").val();

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url:"pnf.php",
             data: { 
             "done":1,
             "comments":comment

              },
             success: function(data){
             }
        })
    }); 
});
```

I have tried many times and don't know what mistake I made, Ajax and jQuery are not working, please anyone help - thanks in advance

Comment: `$("#comment").vol();` -> `$("#comment").val();`

Comment: explain 'not working'..error??

Comment: Your console should have spotted the error. Please always work with your console and network tab while developing

Comment: yes but still same

Comment: please add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of pnf.php then check console error and tell us if PHP/JS error and use ajax response too in `success`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form submit with AJAX passing form data to PHP without page refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616250/form-submit-with-ajax-passing-form-data-to-php-without-page-refresh)

Comment: @hassan that's not only refreshing also insert into database through ajax

Comment: You really should be using prepared statements for mySQL. Someone is going to be able to manipulate your data or just drop your tables, otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made couple of mistakes.

**First**:: You should put *button* `type="button"` in your **HTML form code**
**Second**:: You have made a syntax error. `$("#comment").vol();` should be replaced with `$("#comment").val();` in your **jQuery AJAX**

Comment: i have replaced with  $("#comment").val()  but same result Nothing change

Comment: @MunnaVMC also please ffo the same with first option.

Comment: button type =button ?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you have to send request without refreshing page I modified your JS-code with preventing default submitting form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#commentf").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var comment = $("#comment").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pnf.php",
            data: {
                "done": 1,
                "comments": comment
            },
            success: function (data) {
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is not always the best option.

Comment: @Rana Ghosh in this case it will work. Because I preventing submit event - not clicking the button

Comment: Yes, I know it will work. But i am saying it's not the best practice to do it. This should do when all way is closed. Prefer doing HTML Button `type="button"`.

Comment: @Rana Ghosh So how type=button will help?

Comment: Button `type="button"` will not submit the form by default and will automatically go to click event handler.

Comment: @Rana Ghosh Well you're wrong. Any <button> will submit the form.

Comment: Please go through https://jsfiddle.net/k8hufk7t/ . It will help you to understand

Comment: @Rana Ghosh yes indeed, thanks. Just because default type of <button> is 'submit' it will automatically submit the form. So specifying type will prevent it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: I know. That's why I am saying that.

Answer (score 0):

Modified JQuery Code...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    $("#comq").click(function() {
        var comment=$("#comment").val();

        console.log('comment : '+comment);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"pnf.php",
            data: {
                "done":1,
                "comments":comment
            },
                success: function(data){
            }
        })
    });

});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<form id="commentf" method="post">
    <textarea class="textinput" id="comment" rows="1" name="comments" placeholder="Comment Here......"></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="comq" name="compost" class="butn2" value="Post Comment">
</form> </div>
```

Comment: <button type="button" ? Let you try its not working Also jquary

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I've rectified that one. You can check now. It's working in my Chrome.

Comment: still same results

Comment: In my browser's console, I can able to see the AJAX call. Although it's returning 404 error because I don't have the server side file in my case. What's happening in your case?

Comment: What's happening on your side? Can't you able to see any ajax call happening in your Browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagination();

  var dataSet = {
    comment: $('#comment').val();
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "link.to.your.api/action=compost",
    data: dataSet,
    method: 'post',
    success: function(data){
      console.log('request in success');
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR) {
      console.error('request in error');
      console.log(jqXHR.responseText');
    }
  });
});
```

PHP

```
$action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
swicht($action){
  case 'compost':
    $comment = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comment');
    {
        $reslt_user= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users,`queries` where id='".$_SESSION['id']."' AND  qid= '".$qid."' ");
        $row_lat_lng= mysqli_fetch_array($reslt_user);
        $stmt = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO comments set uid='".$_SESSION['id']."',comments='".$comment."',reply='".$reply."' ,
        qid= '".$qid."' ");
    }
    if(!$stmt)
    {
      http_response_code(400);
      echo 'internal error';        
    } 
    echo 'your data will be saved';
    break;
  default:
    http_response_code(404);
    echo 'unknown action';
}
```

you have to prevent the submit on the form (look in javascript).

after that you send the request to the server and wait for success or error.

in php try to do it with a switch case. and try to not touch super globals directly, use filter_input function.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="commentf" method="post">
    <img width="40px" height="40px" src="uploads/<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>">
    <textarea class="textinput"id="comment" rows="1" name="comments" placeholder="Comment Here......"></textarea>
    <button type="button" id="comq"name="compost" class="butn2">post comment</button>
</form>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#comq").click(function() {
         var comment=$("#comment").val();

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url:"pnf.php",
             data: { 
             "done":1,
             "comments":comment

              },
             success: function(data){
             }
        })
    }); 
});
```

PHP code (pnf.php):

```
comment=$_POST['comments'];
$reslt_user= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users,`queries` where id='".$_SESSION['id']."' AND  qid= '".$qid."' ");
        $row_lat_lng= mysqli_fetch_array($reslt_user);
        $stmt = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO comments set uid='".$_SESSION['id']."',comments='".$comment."',reply='".$reply."' ,
        qid= '".$qid."' ");
    if($stmt)
    {
        echo "hello world";
    }
```

Comment: <button type="button" ?

Comment: used button click for submitting

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery make sure to include jquery libraries before your script file.

latest jquery cdn minified version

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

example

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="yourjsfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: then there is no problem with your code, and must be button type="button"

Comment: button type="button" how its works can you test it please

Comment: i already test, you only need to button click to make ajax call, that's it. you don't need to submit form it self !