# How to make the values entered in controls appear within single quotes in query string

Tags: javascript, php, html

```js
 <script>
  function myFunction() {
    var query = '?';
    var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
    $( "#results" ).text( query += str );
    
  }
  $( "input[type='sel'], input[type='text']" ).on( "submit", myFunction );
  $( "select" ).on( "submit", myFunction );
   myFunction();
  
</script>
```

```html
echo'<input  id="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-success"  name="submit" onclick="myFunction()"/> ';
echo '<p id="results">&nbsp;</p></form>';
```

here it is javascript for to generate  query string for controls   so I have butten with id=submit and event onclick=myFunction

how to  make this work onclick event and also query string should print on the

tag and what will be the code for insertion please let me knoe the answer

for eg:  ?gender='Male'&city='dwd'

Comment: `type="submit"` will make the page submit and not allow the onclick event properly

Comment: then please tell in detail what I should do

Comment: Without cycling through all variables you cannot do this. It's strange to require single quotes around your GET variables. TIP: for every field in your form, add a onkeyup event to take the contents, remove single quotes if it contains any, then add one either side of the contents.

Comment: if you specify why you want to generate query string.. that would be great :)

Comment: sorry I'm getting what you are going to tell

Comment: using that query  passing to php using ajax so I have to insert those values into a table  so I need query string

Comment: query string is generated only when your _method_ is GET. Let me clear you want to get values of html control in php file.. right.?

Comment: ya you are correct. i.e controls are generating dynamically so i need pass values fron javascript to php using ajax

Comment: you need to check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616250/form-submit-with-ajax-passing-form-data-to-php-without-page-refresh#16616315 it doesn't matter if you are generating controls dyanamically

Comment: ya I had gone your link here the problem is every time the number controls are not same it 'll be changing as need so am facing problem

Answer (score 0):

To save the query string in the database you don`t need to do this in javascript, see the following example:

<kbd>test.php</kbd>

```
<form method="post">
    <label> Name
        <input name="query[name]" type="text">
    </label>

    <label> Email
        <input name="query[email]" type="text">
    </label>

    <label> Phone
        <input name="query[phone]" type="text">
    </label>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php

if ($_POST && isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $query = '?'. http_build_query($_POST['query']);

    //save the value of query in the database
    echo $query;
}
```

The above example submit the values of all inputs in an array and build the query using `http_build_query`

and using ajax:

<kbd>test.php</kbd>

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
    <label> Name
        <input name="query[name]" type="text">
    </label>

    <label> Email
        <input name="query[email]" type="text">
    </label>

    <label> Phone
        <input name="query[phone]" type="text">
    </label>
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $('form').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        $.ajax('/ajax.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            data: $('form').serialize()
        })
    });
</script>
```

<kbd>ajax.php</kbd>

```
<?php
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $query = '?'.http_build_query($_POST['query']);

    //save the value of query in the database
    echo $query;
}
```

Comment: but in my case it is different  so I'm not getting how to do