# File send using ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send anytype of file like as image or any format. I can get the file value in jquery but unable to receive that file in php. plz help me any one..
my code bellow/....

index.html

```
<form id="contact-form" action="" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="error-container"></div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control form-control-email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control form-control-subject" name="subject" id="subject" 
                                        placeholder="Position Applying For" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control form-control-message" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="5" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <p>Send us your resume ("doc","docx" or "pdf")</p>
                            <input type="file" id="file_input" name="file">
                            </div>
                            <div id="wait" style="text-align: center !important;width: 100%;display: none;padding-top: 20px;"><img src='images/loader.gif' style="text-align: center!important;margin: auto!important;" width="64" height="64" /><br>Loading..</div>
                            <span class="contact100-form-title" style="font-size: 16px;padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 15px;" id="contact_msg">
                            </span>
                            <div class="text-right"><br>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary solid blank" type="button" id="submit_form">Apply Now</button> 
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Ajax code: -

```
$('#submit_form').click(function(e) {
                var myFile = $('#file_input').prop('files');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",       
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    url: 'ajax/application.php',
                    async: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false, 
                    data:{myFile:myFile},
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert(result);

                    }
                });
            });
```

php code :

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);

 ?>
```

In the php file showing the array empty.....
I m not getting the file in php file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at this: [Form submit with AJAX passing form data to PHP without page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616250/form-submit-with-ajax-passing-form-data-to-php-without-page-refresh)