# how to clear form after submit the form and pass the data to php file without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how to clear form after submit the form and pass the data to php file without reloading page...the form data is pass the php file and it stored the data base.but i was unable to clear the form data after submit the form.if i reset the form using javascrip but data not pass the data base.if i pass the data to php the form is not clear.is there a way for me achive both target?thank you..
here my snipt code...

```
<iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>     
<form action="confirm.php" id="sfm" method="POST" target="votar">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" value="" required/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit My Project " />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using AJAX you can do this.

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function () {
       $.ajax({
          url: 'confirm.php',
          data: $('#sfm').serialize(),
          type: "post",
          success: function (data) {
            $('input[type="text"]').val('');
          }
       });
       return false;
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

in index.php

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>

      $(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              $('#name').val('');
              alert('data');
              //your return value in data
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="ajax.php" id="sfm" method="POST" target="votar">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" value="" required/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit My Project " />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in ajax.php

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
//do what you want to do using name
echo "what you need to return";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about to use Ajax to handle the form submit?

[Form submit with AJAX passing form data to PHP without page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616250/form-submit-with-ajax-passing-form-data-to-php-without-page-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

try making `$_POST` array empty after submitting and saving the form

```
$_POST='';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, first get form inputs value and then `reset`

You can also able to reset after success response

```js
$(function () {
  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this);
    var params = that.serialize();
    that.get(0).reset();
    console.log(params);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'submit.php',
      data: params,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="confirm.php" id="sfm" method="POST" target="votar">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" value="" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit My Project " />
</form>
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
<?php
 $name = $_GET['name'];
 echo 'success';
 exit();
?>
```

Comment: this not pass the data to my data base

Comment: To save in database, you need to do server side code

Comment: this worked sir..I had a mistake in sql..thaku very mutch sir

Answer (score 0):

After getting success response you can clear form input

```
   $('#sfm').submit(function () {
   var form = $(this);
   $.ajax({
      url: 'phpfile.php',
      data: form.serialize(),
      type: "POST",
      success: function (data) {
        $('input[type="text"]').val('');
      }
   });
   return false;
 });
```