# Tag Select - selected option

Tags: html, forms, validation, select, tags

I have a simple form with a select tag, I would like that after clicking on submit, what was marked was remembered.

Could you help me?? How to correct the code below? 
I'm sure that I can't find it correctly on the Internet so I'm asking you for help.

```
<form action="select.php" method="post">
    <select name="select">
        <option value="test1">test1</option>
        <option value="test2">test2</option>
        <option value="test3">test3</option>
        <option value="test4">test4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: You can make an Ajax call to prevent page load. See this [Form submit with AJAX passing form data to PHP without page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616250/form-submit-with-ajax-passing-form-data-to-php-without-page-refresh?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your question is not clear enough, as your question is not that straight forward.

So I am going to give an answer based on an assumption :).

1. I am assuming you want to achieve this with php only.
2. I am assuming that you are using **`POST`** request
3. I am assuming that your **`form action='select.php'`** is the name of the page where your above code reside.

**Submitting the form to the same page.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is the select page</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php 

        $select = '';

        if( isset($_POST['select']) ){
            $select = $_POST['select'];
        }

    ?>

    <form action="select.php" method="post">
        <select name="select">
            <option value="test1" <?php if($select == 'test1'): ?> selected <?php endif; ?>>test1</option>
            <option value="test2" <?php if($select == 'test2'): ?> selected <?php endif; ?>>test2</option>
            <option value="test3" <?php if($select == 'test3'): ?> selected <?php endif; ?>>test3</option>
            <option value="test4" <?php if($select == 'test4'): ?> selected <?php endif; ?>>test4</option>
    </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Submitting the form to different page.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is the select page</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <form action="another-page.php" method="post">
        <select name="select">
            <option value="test1">test1</option>
            <option value="test2">test2</option>
            <option value="test3">test3</option>
            <option value="test4">test4</option>
    </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the `another-page.php` you will have it written like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is the another page</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select name="select2">
            <?php 
                $select = $_POST['select'];
                if( isset($select) ){
                    echo "<option value='{$select}'> {$select} </option>";
                }else{
                    echo "<option value='' selected disabled> Nothing was selected </option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry that I wrote so not clearly, I hope my next posts will be more clear.
Thank you for your comprehensive answer. You are the best! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help;  If it suites your need please mark it as the accepted answer.