# Storing form data with php opens a new page instead of doing it in same page

Tags: php, forms, csv

I have a feedback section at the bottom of my site but when I press submit it opens a new page, I want it to stay on the same page.
https://voxet.net

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $feedback_desc = $_POST['feedback_desc'];
        $cvsData = "$feedback_desc\n";
        $fp = fopen("feedback.csv","a");
        if($fp){
            fwrite($fp,$cvsData);
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
```

When your form submits, it is processed on form.php. That is why there is a redirection to form.php upon form submission. You've got three options:

1) Move the server-side form code from form.php to your page with the form. You can then remove the `action` attribute and there will be no redirect. This will cause the page to refresh though - to avoid this, you need to use AJAX.

2) Add `Header('Location: index.php');` to the end of your `form.php` page. This will redirect back to the home page after submitting the form.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // code
    Header('Location: index.php');
}
```

3) Use AJAX to send the form POST data to form.php upon form submission. See [Form submit with AJAX passing form data to PHP without page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616250/form-submit-with-ajax-passing-form-data-to-php-without-page-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    ..... Code
    header('Location:https://voxet.net')
}
```

Add header function after if statement